# How to interpret "x, x, and x needed"?

Tags: meaning

> It includes an overview of the **testing equipment, software, and
>   samples needed**.

In the example above, does it mean "needed testing equipment, needed software, and needed samples" or "testing equipment, software, and needed samples"? Is it context-dependent or is there any clear way to identify the meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it means "needed testing equipment, needed software, and needed samples." If the intent was to convey the meaning of the second option, they would probably have phrased it the same way you did.
Also, applying context, whatever it is that is providing an overview could not provide an overview of ***all*** software and testing equipment.